# Problema con input tipo select al mantener estilos CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo un imput tipo select que al lado izquierdo muestra lo que se debe ingresar, y me va bien hasta que le inyecto PHP; si yo coloco los  sin php me va perfecto pero si le añado php me da el error y manda salto de linea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div style="padding:0px; margin:0px;display:inline;">
            <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" style="border-bottom-left-radius:2px; border-top-left-radius:2px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 110px; margin-top:0px; background-color:#28b779; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom:0px;"> Bodega</a><select type="text" style=" margin:0px; width:51%; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance : none; border: 1px solid #28b779; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius:2px; border-top-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-left-radius:0px;  border-top-left-radius:0px; margin-bottom:0px; text-align:center;" name="ingresar_selectBodegas" id="ingresar_selectBodegas">

                <?php 
                    for ($i=0 ; $i < count($bodegas); $i++) {   

                            echo '<option value="'.$bodegas[$i]['idBodega'].'">'.$bodegas[$i]['nombre'].'</option>';
                    }?>

            </select></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que quitar los espacios en blanco que hay entre las etiquetas select y de php.
sería algo así: `<select><?php echo 'script php' ?></select>`

Con tu código quedaría así:

```
<div style="padding:0px; margin:0px;display:inline;">
            <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" style="border-bottom-left-radius:2px; border-top-left-radius:2px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 110px; margin-top:0px; background-color:#28b779; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom:0px;"> Bodega</a><select type="text" style=" margin:0px; width:51%; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance : none; border: 1px solid #28b779; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius:2px; border-top-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-left-radius:0px;  border-top-left-radius:0px; margin-bottom:0px; text-align:center;" name="ingresar_selectBodegas" id="ingresar_selectBodegas"><?php 
                    for ($i=0 ; $i < count($bodegas); $i++) {   

                            echo '<option value="'.$bodegas[$i]['idBodega'].'">'.$bodegas[$i]['nombre'].'</option>';
                    }?></select></div>
```